# How to create multiple running totals in one column using SCAN

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My question is about using the scan formula.

I only want to use a formula in C2 and i would like to create a running total for category (column A) A and B. Bonuspoints for the formula works for a undefined amount of categories :)

How can i do this?

[link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fgnO3oBB6P1VN5yYxuDklIyyYHmWqTF8Y8aR2xe6L6o/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding a text based example. Consider sharing an editable example sheet.

Comment: Clear, didn't know that was allowed.

Comment: It's encouraged. Answerers should be more able to answer with tested and completed answers (vs skeletal/conceptual) if you have example sheet. The other thing is that example sheet and formulas directly passed onto your sheet communicate positional relations between cells. So in general, *editable* example sheet could be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(Σ="",,sumif(A2:Σ,Σ,B2:Λ))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already sorted on Column A, you can use `offset` to check whether the previous column A entry is the same as the current one and reset accumulator based on the comparison. For example,

```js
=scan(0,B2:B,lambda(a,c,
        if(isblank(c),,
           if(offset(c,-1,column(A:A)-column(c))=offset(c,0,column(A:A)-column(c)),
              a+c,
              c)))
```

For un-sorted data, you can either sort it first (<-- should be computationally more efficient) or use `filter`.